# Time complexity of sort with a limit

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

Let's take three different sorts: Selection, Bubble, and Quick. Here is how they perform with an array of size `n`:

- Selection: O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the average and worst cases
- Bubble: O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the average and worst cases
- Quicksort: O(n log n), O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the average and worst cases

With a limit of L applied to them, what would be the time complexity of the sort? My guess was the answer would be: O(nL) and O(n log L) -- is that correct? Why or why not? Additionally, is there a particular type of array sort that performs better than others when doing a sort-with-limit?

For example:

```
a = [1, 4, 2, 7, 4, 22, 49, 0, 2]
sort(a, limit=4)
==> [0, 1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Assuming by "Quick" you mean quicksort, the worst case is O(n^2), not O(n log n). It is not at all clear what you mean by "a limit of L"; what specifically is limited by L?

Comment: @kaya3 I mean the number of elements to return. So if the full sort would be `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY a` the limited sort would be `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY a LIMIT L`

Comment: @kaya3 yes, thank you. Updated for quicksort

Comment: Well, how do you change quicksort to return only L elements? It doesn't sort the array one element at a time, unlike the other two algorithms you named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selection sort:
The time complexity for selection sort is going to be O(nL). In selection sort, we append the next smallest element in the unsorted part of the list to the sorted part of the list. Since we only need L sorted elements, we only need to iterate L times. In each iteration, we have to iterate through the unsorted part of the list to find the smallest element, so we need a total of n*L iterations. This leads to O(nL).

Bubble sort:
The time complexity for selection sort is going to be O(nL). The regular bubble sort puts the current largest element to the end of the list after each iteration. We can modify the bubble sort such that in each iteration we put the smallest element to the front of the list. Instead of starting from the start of the array, we start from the end of the array. We only need L iterations to find the L sorted elements, so the time complexity becomes O(nL).

Quick sort:
Quick sort divides the array into two parts and sorts each part using recursion. The time complexity will still be O(log(n)*n) because there is no "check point" in quick sort. We never have a partial sorted list that contains the L smallest elements when we are doing quick sort.

Merge sort:
The idea here is similar to that of quick sort. We have to reach the base case of the recursion and merge the results to get a fully sorted list, so we still have O(log(n)*n) running time.